# How to monitor bunch of Ubuntu machines for CPU usage from another machine?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, monitoring

I have couple of machines as shown below which are running Ubuntu 12.04 and I need to find out the process name along with its pid whose CPU usage is greater than 70%.

Below are the machines as an example -

```
machineA
machineB
machineC
machineD
```

I need to have my shell script which can run periodically every 15 minutes and check whether any of the above machines has CPU usage greater than 70%. If there are any machines which are having CPU usage as greater than 70%, then send out an email with the machine name and the process name along with it's id.

I will be running my shell script from `machineX` and I have passwordless ssh key setup for user `david` from machineX to all the above machines.

What is the best way to do all these kind of monitoring?

I have below command which can get me `PID, %CPU and COMMAND name` of the process whose CPU usage is greater than 70%.

```
ps aux --sort=-%cpu | awk 'NR==1{print $2,$3,$11}NR>1{if($3>=70) print $2,$3,$11}'
```

Not sure how to fully automate this process?

Comment: This seems like a better question for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: If you don't have a particular reason to build your own, there are plenty of existing monitoring systems that can do this (and much more).

Comment: @AndrewMedico Can you provide any example which I can take a look?

Comment: Another option on stackexchange is http://askubuntu.com . But the best way to do monitoring of more than 1 machine is to install proper monitoring software and use the applications provided. You can do it now, or you can do it later when management has a brain-storm ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Hey men you are doing something wrong there, the cpu there its peak cpu in the current execution gap. That means that in the next second this proccess may not be eating any resources. Its better to use a different way to catch up cpu hungry proccess. My prefered way its by cpu time. Have a look on this example:

```
panos@wintermute:~$ ps xafu
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:53   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:53   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:53   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:53   0:02  \_ [rcu_sched]
```

TIME: is the cpu time a proccess has bean eat. normal proccess dont need to eat much cpu proccess. So by creating a simple shell script with a small loop you could gather the information you need. The shell script could looked like:

```
#!/bin/sh
date
for i in "a b c d" ; do

echo machine${i}
ssh machine${i} ps xau|awk 'NR==1{print $2,$10,$11}NR>1{if($10>=5) print $2,$10,$11}'
echo -- --

done
exit
```

That will match any proccess that has bean eat 5 minutes of cpu

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you help me to understand what does this line do `ps xau|awk 'NR==1{print $2,$10,$11}NR>1{if($10>=5) print $2,$10,$11}'`?

Answer (score 1):

AWK does row-oriented editing (and a bunch of other stuff too).
A block of statements enclosed in brackets {} will be executed on each row of input.This behaviour may be limited by prefixing the block with a condition (in ordinary C syntax)

NR==1 {} means that block will be executed on a first input row. In the example above fields 2, 10 and 11 from the first input row will be printed on a single row.
NR>1 {} means that block will be executed for each row after the first one.